# Add Table Caption Number R-Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kable

I am having trouble understanding how to add a table of figure caption number to a table in R-Markdown. I'm using `bookdown` and have been trying to understand the [2.5 tables](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html) portion of the documentation.

It says when you add a caption to the `kable` function it will automatically be labeled an numbered. However, I am only getting the "text" portion of the label without the number.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "x"
date: "February 20, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

```{r libraries, echo=FALSE}
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = T)
library(kableExtra)
library(bookdown)
```


```{r example, echo=T}

head(pressure) %>%
  kable(caption = "Pressure",
        booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)

```
````

Your help in understanding how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: fig.cap adds captions to figure. If you want a table caption you should use the caption argument in kable.

Comment: Thank you. I am having problems with both tables and functions but edited my code to not be conflicting. I am still getting the same problem with the `kable` function where it only produces the caption without a reference number.

Comment: When I post your code into the sample bookdown project in RStudio, I get a numbered caption.  So I think you've got a conflict with something else that you're doing, but we have no information on what, since you haven't posted a complete example.

Comment: @user2554330 I have posted a full example. Can you please provide the difference in you example?

Comment: Mine was a `bookdown` project, yours isn't.

Comment: @user2554330 i am little new to `bookdown`. are you saying i need to set up the index markdown file first?

Comment: I don't know `bookdown` either.  I'm saying I set up the sample bookdown project in RStudio, and modified it to include your code.    It's got the index file and lots of other stuff as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `bookdown` but `rmarkdown::html_document()` due to the `output` header. You need to change your header to

```
---
title: "test"
author: "x"
date: "February 20, 2019"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---
```

in order to use `bookdown` features within a single file project. For actual books it is a good idea to let the `bookdown` package set-up a skeleton for you, e.g. via the RStudio add-in.